# What exactly does WifiManager.setWifiEnabled() return?

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

Does any of you have experience with return value of `setWifiEnabled()`?

Documentation is unclear, it says:

> Returns **true** if the operation succeeds (or if the existing state is the same as the requested state).

What it does when operation fails? Does it throw exception or return `false`?

Is it possible to do something like:

```
if (!WifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true)) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Wifi switch failed.");
} else {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Wifi switch succeeded.")
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at implementation of [WifiService#setWifiEnabled(boolean)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/services/java/com/android/server/WifiService.java#625):

```
    /**
     * see {@link android.net.wifi.WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean)}
     * @param enable {@code true} to enable, {@code false} to disable.
     * @return {@code true} if the enable/disable operation was
     *         started or is already in the queue.
     */
    public synchronized boolean setWifiEnabled(boolean enable) {
        enforceChangePermission();
        Slog.d(TAG, "setWifiEnabled: " + enable + " pid=" + Binder.getCallingPid()
                    + ", uid=" + Binder.getCallingUid());
        if (DBG) {
            Slog.e(TAG, "Invoking mWifiStateMachine.setWifiEnabled\n");
        }
        if (enable) {
            reportStartWorkSource();
        }
        mWifiStateMachine.setWifiEnabled(enable);
        /*
         * Caller might not have WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS,
         * only CHANGE_WIFI_STATE is enforced
         */
        long ident = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
        try {
            handleWifiToggled(enable);
        } finally {
            Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(ident);
        }
        if (enable) {
            if (!mIsReceiverRegistered) {
                registerForBroadcasts();
                mIsReceiverRegistered = true;
            }
        } else if (mIsReceiverRegistered) {
            mContext.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            mIsReceiverRegistered = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So, it never returns `false`. If for some reason the desired operation couldn't succeed, then exception will be thrown, see [WifiManager.setWifiEnabled(boolean)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#L1625):

```
    /**
     * Enable or disable Wi-Fi.
     * @param enabled {@code true} to enable, {@code false} to disable.
     * @return {@code true} if the operation succeeds (or if the existing state
     *         is the same as the requested state).
     */
    public boolean setWifiEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        try {
            return mService.setWifiEnabled(enabled);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            throw e.rethrowFromSystemServer();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am new to Java so I wasn't 100% sure. Now I am :-)

Comment: This code may be outdated because I've seen it return false on my galaxy s10.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is outdated (source is from android 4.2 where current android is now 10 and 11 will be out soon). This method can return false. [WifiServiceImpl.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/master/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiServiceImpl.java) is the current source for handling [WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean)):

Code:

```
 /**
 * see {@link android.net.wifi.WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean)}
 * @param enable {@code true} to enable, {@code false} to disable.
 * @return {@code true} if the enable/disable operation was
 *         started or is already in the queue.
 */
@Override
public synchronized boolean setWifiEnabled(String packageName, boolean enable) {
    if (enforceChangePermission(packageName) != MODE_ALLOWED) {
        return false;
    }
    boolean isPrivileged = isPrivileged(Binder.getCallingPid(), Binder.getCallingUid());
    if (!isPrivileged && !isDeviceOrProfileOwner(Binder.getCallingUid())
            && !mWifiPermissionsUtil.isTargetSdkLessThan(packageName, Build.VERSION_CODES.Q,
              Binder.getCallingUid())
            && !isSystem(packageName, Binder.getCallingUid())) {
        mLog.info("setWifiEnabled not allowed for uid=%")
                .c(Binder.getCallingUid()).flush();
        return false;
    }
    // If Airplane mode is enabled, only privileged apps are allowed to toggle Wifi
    if (mSettingsStore.isAirplaneModeOn() && !isPrivileged) {
        mLog.err("setWifiEnabled in Airplane mode: only Settings can toggle wifi").flush();
        return false;
    }
    // If SoftAp is enabled, only privileged apps are allowed to toggle wifi
    boolean apEnabled = mWifiApState == WifiManager.WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLED;
    if (apEnabled && !isPrivileged) {
        mLog.err("setWifiEnabled SoftAp enabled: only Settings can toggle wifi").flush();
        return false;
    }
    // If we're in crypt debounce, ignore any wifi state change APIs.
    if (mFrameworkFacade.inStorageManagerCryptKeeperBounce()) {
        return false;
    }
    mLog.info("setWifiEnabled package=% uid=% enable=%").c(packageName)
            .c(Binder.getCallingUid()).c(enable).flush();
    long ident = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
    try {
        if (!mSettingsStore.handleWifiToggled(enable)) {
            // Nothing to do if wifi cannot be toggled
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(ident);
    }
    mWifiMetrics.incrementNumWifiToggles(isPrivileged, enable);
    mWifiController.sendMessage(CMD_WIFI_TOGGLED);
    return true;
}
```